# How do I create a new series in a Pandas DataFrame and populate it with specific values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to coding in Python and seeking a little guidance using Pandas.

In brief, I would like to create a new series in a Pandas DataFrame and then populate it.
I’ve recreated a simple example to illustrate my specific problem.

In my example, I am attempting to use a dictionary of car Makes (Model_Dict), and a function called Make_Calculator, to populate a new series in my DataFrame called “Make”.  The function compares the car model type in the DataFrame series “Model” to a dictionary with Car-Model as the key and Car-Make as the values.  The function is supposed to create, and then assign, the Car Make to a new series called “Make” in the DataFrame.  When I run this, it creates a new series called “Make”, but every row was populated with “unassigned” as opposed to the actual make of the vehicle.

I am very new to Pandas, any assistance would be much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

car_inventory = {'Model' : ['Versa', 'Focus', 'Outback'],
                 'Color' : ['Red', 'Brown', 'Green']}

car_df = pd.DataFrame(car_inventory)

Model_Dict = {'Versa': 'Nissan', 'Focus' : 'Ford', 'Outback':'Nissan'}

def Make_Calculator():
    for model,make in Model_Dict.items():
        for i in car_df['Model']:
            if i == model:
                car_df['Make'] = make
            else:
                car_df['Make'] = 'unassigned'

Make_Calculator()
```

Comment: The [df.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) function is what you are looking for. `car_df['Make'] = car_df['Model'].map(Model_Dict)` will populate the Make column based on your dictionary.

Comment: A thread outlining a similar issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57350896/use-a-python-dictionary-as-a-lookup-table-to-output-new-values).

Comment: Owen, Thanks! This solved my issue.  Also, I appreciate you sharing the thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to get information using a dictionary, I think you can find how to do this here if you are starting with pandas: [Pandas Dict to Dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)

Comment: Thanks tylerjames!

Comment: np! Dolicho if you are new to pandas I would suggest reading through [10 minutes to pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html) even though its a little bit of a read.